# Проблема с массивом, не записывает данные

Tags: java, массивы

Есть проблема с массивом:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Filter extends Input {
int [] D, C;

Filter(){
    for (int q = 0; q < 10; q++){
        C = new int[10];
        service_id();
        System.out.println("service_ID generated out_id = " + out_id);
        C[q] = out_id;
        System.out.println("в C[" + q +"] " + "должно запихнутся: " + out_id + "\n");
    }
    System.out.println("Массив: " + Arrays.toString(C));
}
}
```

out:

```
service_ID generated out_id = 1
в C[0] должно запихнуть: 1

service_ID generated out_id = 4
в C[1] должно запихнуть: 4

service_ID generated out_id = 7
в C[2] должно запихнуть: 7

service_ID generated out_id = 8
в C[3] должно запихнуть: 8

service_ID generated out_id = 2
в C[4] должно запихнуть: 2

service_ID generated out_id = 2
в C[5] должно запихнуть: 2

service_ID generated out_id = 8
в C[6] должно запихнуть: 8

service_ID generated out_id = 3
в C[7] должно запихнуть: 3

service_ID generated out_id = 3
в C[8] должно запихнуть: 3

service_ID generated out_id = 6
в C[9] должно запихнуть: 6

Массив: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6]
```

Как видим, почему-то массив не записывает данные.... Помогите решить проблему пожалуйста.

Вот используемые коды:
Input:

```
class Input extends Model {
int out_id;

void service_id() {
    int randomV = (int)(Math.random()*data_serv.length);
    out_id = data_serv[randomV];
}}
```

Model создает массив сервис:

```
serviceArray(10);
```

и класс Дата:

```
class Data {
int[] data_serv;
void serviceArray(int size){
    data_serv = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < data_serv.length; i++){
        data_serv[i] = i + 1;
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас на каждой итерации цикла создаётся новый пустой массив и затирает предыдущий. Вынесите операцию создания массива за пределы цикла:

```
C = new int[10];
for (int q = 0; q < 10; q++){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Очень больше спасибо, что-то упустил этот момент.

Comment: @ЮрийИва [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)